# Python Jupyter _NameError: name 'data' is not defined_ Even tho data is defined

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Ok so I am just exploring data and I ran into this error. I have defined the data earlier but when I tried to run a function *data['title']* , it shows an error that data is not defined.
My code

```
import pandas as pd 
Importing Pandas
names = ('ids','title','year','rating','votes','length','genre')
data = pd.read_csv('imdb_top_10000.txt', sep="\t", names=names , index_col = 1)
```

when i tried this function

```
data['title']
```

It showed me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-19640b13f9cb> in <module>
----> 1 data['title']

NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

I performed some other functions in between this, like

```
data.head()
```

and this worked alright

some pictures

[image]

Comment: Can you show the output of ```data.head()```?

Comment: Is it possible you have whitespace around the commas? Like 'title ,' in the actual CSV? names would not fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the problem is in the separator, when trying to read the csv file. So if you don't put the correct separator, pandas will read your csv file in one column.

To check if this is the problem, type

```
data.shape
```

you will get the number of rows and columns (If the number of columns = 1 , you just have to put the right séparator)